# FMDB and threads and queues

Tags: ios, multithreading, fmdb

I'm playing with FMDB which is a database wrapper for SQLite on iOS.
it doesn't support multi threads, and it provides a queue , of course a serial queue, to execute SQL one by one (FMDatabaseQueue),

In my project, I use this queue(FMDatabaseQueue) for all queries, which make sure the thread safe.

My question is, if I  use this queue, and besides , I wanna do a query, in main thread,
this means we have 2 threads: main and the queue, it will make the thread unsafe,  but I simply wanna do this query, and dont wanna wait the tasks in queue to finish,(assume these is no data issue, manipulate different tables), what is the best way? or I'd better use the queue, and have no more choices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only ever reading data, you might check out FMDatabasePool.

If you want to do things asynchronously - then you can throw your queue update inside a dispatch block and go along your merry way.